# Task scheduler not executing Python containing Xlwings library

Tags: python, xlwings

I have a Python script which I uploaded into task scheduler but it returns 0x1 error. The script is running well in cmd/visual studio code.

I have tried the following steps but it does not work.

- removed Run with highest privilege option
- Include the full path name in the Start in option

I am using xlwings library because I have some formulas in my excel file which return as NaN with pandas library. Hence I used xlwings to copy the data and paste as values only without the formula into another column. But it appears that there is issues with the task scheduler when xlwings is used. Could anyone advise what I should do?

Comment: Are you running it as a user that has permission to your file?  Are you providing the whole path to Python?

Comment: Yes I am providing the full path name and I’m running it with my own user account and accessing the files in my own documents folder

Comment: Is xlwings installed in a virtual environment, or is it installed system-wide?

Comment: It’s not in virtual environment.. it’s installed in my C drive

Comment: Well you can try running it from a batch file rather than directly (which I assume is what you are doing). Direct the output of the batch to a file if there is any expected output.